# How to call procedures directly from interactive sql

Tags: database, sybase

Guys I'm trying to do some checking on a database domains and in order to do that I need to call and see directly substr procedure. Yet I'm getting an error that this procedure hasn't been found. How so? This is supposed to be built-in procedure. How can I call it and get result from it, directly in interactive sql?

Comment: Probably telling us what database server you're using is going to help you get some answers. Just "Interactive SQL" alone does not seem to identify a single possible candidate.

Comment: can you post the call you have made?

Comment: @GulliMeel I called it with: call substr('0000',1,2)

Answer (score 1):

First of all in Sybase ASE it is substring and not substr and it is a function so you need to use the select or something like that to run this..
try below

```
select substring('0000',1,2)
```